# How do I configure the place of the Netbeans .netbeans directory?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.1

I want Netbeans 6.1 to store the .netbeans directory in another place than the default. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify this when you run Netbeans IDE via the command line. This is useful if you want to have different profiles/working environments in the IDE or when you are testing out Netbeans IDE plug-ins. This works from 5.0 to the current version (6.5).

Simply specify "--userdir " on the command line. Example:

netbeans --userdir /local/file/system/netbeans/userdir/6.1

Answer (score 0):

There's config file:

```
 <Netbeans>/etc/netbeans.conf

 netbeans_default_userdir=<dir>
```